# How to replace "()" from extracted text with some other character in Imacros

Tags: imacros

I want to extract image name and then use the name to save the image
here is the js code that i use

```html
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:txt2ArtikelNr EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
...
...
..
macro += "ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE={{!EXTRACT}}.jpg WAIT=YES" + "\n";
```

It works fine until there are brackets () in the image name. In this case it does not download the image.

e.g. If image name A123, it works fine.

```
 If image name A (123), it does not download image
  and gives me this error wrong format of SET command, line 4 (Error code: 910)
```

Thanks in advance

I am using  firefox 38.0.5, and imacros addon 8.9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\(\\)]/g, '');")
```

If you want to replace the space sign as well, just add it into the square brackets.

---

And here is the code for your js-script:

```
macro += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.replace(/[\(\)]/g, \'\');")' + "\n";
```

Comment: First of all thank you for being always there to help. I tried your code, but it shows the same error if there is space or () in the name

Comment: Hello, @Mir. I think that the problem is in spaces. Try to apply this line: `macro += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.replace(/[\(\)]/g, \'\').replace(/ /g, \'<SP>\');")' + "\n";` or if you don’t need them in the file names: `macro += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.replace(/[ \(\)]/g, \'\');")' + "\n";` .